# removing char in string after space

Tags: html, whitespace

I'm having problem with that java framework seems to remove the content of a string after a space character.

code example

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" size="25" value=<%=Name%>>
```

If Name is equal to "This is my name" the input text only show "This".

I'm guessing this is to avoid xss problems but I need to be able to use strings that contain space so how do I get around this? (i'm using tomcat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes around the *value* of your value attribute.

This is always the case in **HTML** when attribute values contain spaces.

(ie it has nothing to do with Java)

It should look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" size="25" value="<%= Name %>">
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do...  `value="<%=Name%>"`

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" size="25" value="<%=Name%>">
```